# Postgres complex insert or update with 2 unique constraints

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has these key columns. Other columns are present but these are the key columns for this question.

```
user_id: string,
external_id: string
disabled_by: string
```

Additional notes:

1. All columns have the not null constraint.
2. unique constraint ('external_id_constraint_1') (external_id, disabled_by)
3. unique constraint ('external_id_constraint_2') (user_id, external_id)

Operations:

**Add external id**

Adding an new external id for user 1 it would look like this:

`insert into external_ids (user_id, external_id, disabled_by) values ('user1', 'exid2', '');`

**Disabling an external id**

If the external id is later revoked for user 1:

`update external_ids set disabled_by='admin1' where user_id='user1' and external_id='exid2';`

**Reenabling the external_id**

A user can't have more than 1 entry for a given external_id. If a row exists ('user1', 'exid2', 'admin1') then the row needs to be updated:

`update external_ids set disabled_by='' where user_id='user1' and external_id='exid2';`

Rather than a new row being created. However another user between the disable and the reenable attempt could have claimed the external_id. If this has happened the update should do nothing.

**Solutions attempted**

I am trying to get a single postgres sql statement to handle this case.

Things I tried:

1. an insert into .... on conflict on constraint ... except that I need to handle 2 different constraint violations differently.
2. update does not have the ability to do the insert if there is nothing to update
3. update doesn't have the ability to handle a constraint violation.

Question:

*Is it possible to do this in a single sql statement or am I doomed to be frustrated.*

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this in a single statement?

Comment: @CL I assume you are asking this question because you will be answering the question. I hope you are not just wasting my time. The reason is: the software framework expects to execute a single sql command and return the results.  Executing multiple sql commands becomes more complex. A stored procedure is similarly problematic as sql stored procedures require internal review and have deployment issues because of versioning problems.

Now I am eagerly awaiting your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine multiple data-modifying statements by [putting them into WITHs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH constraint_1 AS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM external_ids
  WHERE external_id = $2
    AND disabled_by = ''
),
constraint_2 AS (
  UPDATE external_ids
  SET disabled_by = ''
  WHERE user_id     = $1
    AND external_id = $2
    AND disabled_by <> ''
  RETURNING 1
)
INSERT INTO external_ids (user_id, external_id, disabled_by)
SELECT $1, $2, ''
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM constraint_1)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM constraint_2);
```

Like the equivalent stored procedure, this might have races with concurrent updates, depending on the transaction isolation level.